# Is it possible to recursively print out a pattern affected by the parameter?

Tags: java

I've been curious about this as I was learning recursion.

I'm aware of recursive print methods like

```
public static void countdown(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("Blastoff!");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println(n);
        countdown(n - 1);
    }
}
```

And ones that create "pyramids"
But what about a pattern that's not simplistic or easy to code?
For example,

```
public static void pattern(int n){
code;
}

Output if pattern(2);
+
++
+

Output if pattern(3):

+
++
+
+++
+
++
+ 

Output if pattern(4):
+
++
+ 
+++
+
++++
+
+++
+
++
+
```

I've been at the drawing board for a decent amount of time trying to figure out how someone would code/approach this. I tried it with the modulo operator, but the issue with it is limitation due to n being any # greater than 0.

I have also tried having cases, but that does not work either due to n being some number.

Comment: Recursion works well when the n-th operation can be calculated based on the n-1-th result. There doesn't seem to be such a pattern in your examples and recursion is probably not well suited to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, if you want to use recursion but the parameters in the method header don't really lend themselves to it, then it's standard to make a helper method whose parameters are more appropriate, and internally call that.

In python, or another language that supports default parameters, you'd just make `k`'s default value fill itself in from `n`, and expect callers to not provide it.

I've implemented your case as a recursion (it has different paths for if it's increasing, decreasing, or in the middle - and in either direction, it iterates in a range of `[2 .. 2n-2]` with `n` as the midpoint). It's kind of clumsy and could certainly be optimized, but you can get the picture - this is an awkward case to handle with recursion, it would be more straightforward with a simple `while` loop.

```
public static void pattern(int n) {
    _pattern(n, n);
}

private static void _pattern(int n, int k) {
    // calculate number of characters to print
    int d = n - Math.abs(k - n);
    // base case - do nothing
    if (d < 2) {
        return;
    }
    // recursive flow
    // note that, for the initial run, _both_ if statements activate
    if (k <= n) {
        _pattern(n, k - 1);
        System.out.println("+");
    }
    System.out.println("+".repeat(d));
    if (k >= n) {
        System.out.println("+");
        _pattern(n, k + 1);
    }
}
```